# join lists based on common head or tail

Tags: python, list, join, tail, head

What is the fastest way to solve the following
I will to join several lists based on common head or tail

```
input = ([5,6,7], [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [8, 9])
output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: what do you mean by common head or tail. ? you should elaborate on how you get the output

Comment: I would like a method that can join [5,6,7] and [3,4,5] on 5 to form [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and [1,2,3] to this output on 3 to form [1, 2, 3 4, 5, 6, 7]

Comment: what about `([1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6])` case?

Comment: There might be ambiguities about which lists to join.

Comment: Oeps! Interesting case, the element of my input are all triplets, this case will never happened.

Comment: what about ([1,2,3], [3,4,1]) or any other combination that can form a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def chain(inp):
    d = {}
    for i in inp:
        d[i[0]] = i[:], i[-1]
    l, n = d.pop(min(d))
    while True:
        lt, n = d.pop(n, [None, None])
        if n is None:
            if len(d) == len(inp) - 1:
                l, n = d.pop(min(d))
                continue
            break
        l += lt[1:]
    return l

>>> chain(input)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> chain(([5,6,7], [1,2,10], [3,4,5], [8, 9]))
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks SilentGhost. It's general enough (str and int) and works perfectly. Are there any general name for this type of method. I call it 'tiling list'

Comment: input = ([5,6,7], [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [8, 9], [9, 10, 11], [12])
output = ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11])

is recursion a good idea for this case?

Comment: input = ([5,6,7], [1,2,10], [3,4,5], [8, 9])
output = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Oeps! the previous won't work if given the above input

Comment: given the above input, you just need to check `d` and run my code again, therefore obtaining `[8,9,10,11]` list. in your second example you could do the same, but it's not clear on what ground would you have excluded `[1, 2, 10]` and `[8,9]` lists.

Comment: [3,4,5] and [5,6,7] are joining because [3,4,5] has a tail 5 and [5,6,7] have a head 5.